# forループ中にスライダーの値を反映させたい

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

jupyternotebook上で、ループを使ってグラフを描画するときに途中で変数の値(下の例ではb)を変更したいのですができますか？
途中で値を変えたときにグラフがどのように変化するかをシミュレーションするプログラムを作成中です。
下記のようにスライダーを使って変更しようとしたら、forループが終了するまでbの値の変更が反映されません。
また、スライダーを動かした場合、ループ終了後にグラフが消えます。

```
import matplotlib
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
from IPython.display import display, clear_output
from ipywidgets import interact

b=0
x=[]
y=[]

def f(a):
    global b
    b=a+1
    print(b)

interact(f,a=(-10,10, 1))

fig = plt.figure()
axe = fig.add_subplot(111)

for i in range(10):
    x.append(i)
    y.append(i+b)
    axe.plot(x,y)
    display(fig)
    time.sleep(1)
    axe.cla()
    clear_output(wait = True)
```

ご教示よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

載せて頂いたコードの場合、for文が終わるまで関数fが実行されないことが問題かと思います。これを回避するためのコードを書いてみました。

```
%matplotlib notebook 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from ipywidgets import interact

b=0

def f(a):
    global b
    b=a+1
    print(b)

interact(f,a=(-10, 10, 1))

# figureとaxesを作成
fig, axe = plt.subplots()

# 変数の初期化
idx = 0
x, y = [], []

# 描画関数
# def plot_func(timer, fig, axe):
def plot_func(timer):
    global x, y, b, idx
    global fix, axe
    x.append(idx)
    y.append(idx+b)
    # if idx >= 1:
    if idx >= 10:
        timer.stop()
        return
    axe.plot(x, y)
    axe.set_title('(x, y) = (%d, %d) @index:%d'%(x[-1], y[-1], idx))
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()

    idx += 1

# 以前に作成したtimerがあれば削除する
if 'timer' in locals():
    timer.stop()
    del timer

# 描画更新のトリガーとなるタイマーの作成
timer = fig.canvas.new_timer(interval=1000)
# timer.add_callback(plot_func, fig, axe, timer)
timer.add_callback(plot_func, timer)
timer.start()

plt.show()
```

一行目で

```
%matploblib notebook
```

は、Jupyter上でmatplotlibの描画更新のための機能(callback)に必要なmagic commandです。callback関数(この場合plot_func)内のエラーが発生すると、エラーメッセージが表示されることなく停止する場合があります。このため、デバグが非常にやりにくいので、callback関数の内容変更には十分注意して行ってください。

追記@2017/11/25
ソースコードを修正しました。

Comment: 記載して頂いたコードを実行しましたが動きませんでした。  グラフが更新されませんし、やはりスライダーを動かすとグラフが消えます。

Comment: @R.O さん、いくつか不具合がある状態でした。ソースコードを修正して動作確認しましたので、もしよければ再度お試しください。

Comment: 早速ありがとうございます！ただ、修正して頂いたコードでグラフは動きだしましたが、やはりスライダーを動かすとグラフが消えてしまいます。dkatoさんの環境ではスライダーの値が反映されているのでしょうか？

Comment: 私の環境ではスライダーを動かしてもグラフは残ったままで消えることはないのですが・・・MBP macOS 10.13.1, Chrome, Anaconda distributionでインストールした環境を使っています。

Comment: では、私の環境の問題のようですね。私はwindows10,chrome,Anacondaです。これは別の問題なので自分で調べて分からなければ再度スレッド立てます。もし、何かわかることがあればコメント頂けると助かります。この件ほとんどあきらめていたのに丁寧にご回答頂きありがとうございました。

Comment: 私もWindows環境で今度試してみます。